# Correctly using crypt() with SHA512 in PHP

Tags: php, password-encryption, crypt

All the examples online show the use of crypt like this:

```
$pass = crypt('something','$6$rounds=5000$anexamplestringforsalt$');
```

But everyone says that you are not supposed to define the rounds or the salt.

So how should I use it?

Also I am having a problem: when I run the code above, it only runs 50 rounds instead of 5000 rounds as if the system is stopping it.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**//- Solution -//**

I have found some of these to be useful:

**For generating Salt:**

Here is a random way of generating salt

```
$randomString = random_bytes(32);
```

Base 64 encode to ensure that some characters will not cause problems for crypt

```
$salt = base64_encode($randomString);
```

**For Hashing:**

```
$hashed = crypt($passwordInput, '$6$'.$salt);
```

**To Confirm:**

```
if (crypt($passwordInput, $hashed) == $hashed) { 
  // Valid action
} else { 
  // Invalid action
}
```

** Special Thanks to @**lathspell** for help with arriving at above solution **

Comment: Out of interest: how are you determining how many rounds it actually does?

Comment: Because the output shows: $6$rounds=50$ob0t0FFYzA4Az0FlWjjOaXzflUuCfQn8qKrA75JRgoiElmy35zLVF7u4558SxPXoNWSaUmLDKxPYDtpvuWIWs1

Comment: Possibly a bug in some older versions? → http://3v4l.org/BplEG Actually, according to the manual SHA-512 did not exist until 5.3.2...!?

Comment: Ok @deceze 's suggestion that it may be a bug is correct, I checked my CP and turned out it jumped back to PHP 5.2. I'll have to figure out why later. Also, Is there an answer for the Main question? about how it should be displayed.

Comment: I removed the code to generate a password with `str_shuffle` because it has max 32 bits of entropy and likely less (because `str_shuffle` is not cryptagraphically secure)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main reason to run the algorithm for a certain amount of rounds is simply to slow it down to make brute forcing attacks uninteresting. For that 5000 iterations are enough even for modern hardware. You could as well use 100000 but then your server admin would probably want to have a word with you :-)
rounds=5000 is the default for SHA-512. The minimum is 1000 and the maximum very high.

Comment: So how would I write the php code for the generally accepted SHA-512 Crypt Algo?

Comment: for encryption:

    $salt = substr(str_shuffle("./ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"), 0, 8);
    $hashed = crypt($passwordInput, '$6$'.$salt);

to verify:

    if (crypt($passwordInput, $hashed) == $hashed) {
      echo "valid";
    } else {
      echo "invalid";
    }

Comment: Ok Thank You! I will make a post with what I will use.

Comment: You could throw in a str_repeat() before the str_shuffle()

Comment: To not be vulnerable to timing attacks one should use the `hash_equals` function instead of `==`.

Answer (score 5):

Use OpenSSL for salt generation, it's even more random. And maybe 20000 rounds to future proof your code a bit.

```
function cryptPassword($password, $salt = "", $rounds = 20000)
{
    if ($salt == "")
    {
        // Generate random salt
        $salt = substr(bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16)),0,16);
    }
    // $6$ specifies SHA512
    $hash = crypt($password, sprintf('$6$rounds=%d$%s$', $rounds, $salt));

    return $hash;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

hash could be an option. You can use `hash('sha512', $stringInput);`

Comment: I suggest you think about the fact if it is useful to answer an already answered question that is 8 years old.