# laravel reset password using auth and SHA512 encryption

Tags: laravel, authentication, traits, laravel-5.6, reset-password

I am working with laravel auth and resetting password using ResetsPasswords Trait
with SHA512 encryption here is my code of ResetPassowrds trait

```
/**
 * Reset the given user's password.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword  $user
 * @param  string  $password
 * @return void
 */
protected function resetPassword($user, $password)
{
    $user->password = hash('sha512',$password);

    $user->setRememberToken(Str::random(60));

    $user->save();

    event(new PasswordReset($user));

    $this->guard()->login($user);
}
```

code is working properly in local but when i switch to server the password got updated in bcrypt how to resolve this...?

Comment: use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;    and then $user->password = Hash::make($password);  Not SHA512 but should work.

Comment: @BradGoldsmith but i need to convert it in SHA512 not in bcrypt.

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/encrypt-sha512    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18305789/correctly-using-crypt-with-sha512-in-php .   Maybe these links will help.  Sorry I could not have been more assistance.